# How to catch error from a forked child process?

Tags: node.js, child-process

Node.js v8.11.1

There are two files: parent.js and child.js.

Parent

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');

const forked = fork('./child');

forked.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Message from child', msg);
  forked.kill();
});

forked.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Error from child', err);
});

forked.send({ hello: 'world' });
```

Child

```
process.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Message from parent:', msg);
});

try {
  let counter = 0;

  seTimeout(() => {
    process.send({ counter: counter++ });
  }, 1000);
} catch (err) {
  throw new Error('not good: ' + err);
}
```

There is an intentional typo in the child script - `seTimeout`. When I execute parent `node parent.js`, I get:

```
/media/trex/safe/Development/child.js:12
  throw new Error('not good: ' + err);
  ^

Error: not good: ReferenceError: seTimeout is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/trex/safe/Development/siren/sentinl-private/server/lib/actions/report/child.js:12:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

The error was not caught by the parent. How to catch the error by the parent?

#### Update 1

As I see here https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15734 this is working as intended. Maybe there is another event to catch errors or something else?

#### Update 2

Now I can catch an error the following way. But I'm not sure it is the best way to do it.

Parent

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');

const forked = fork('./child');

forked.on('message', (msg) => {
  if (msg.error) {
    console.error(msg.error);
  } else {
    console.log('Message from child', msg);
  }
  forked.kill();
});

forked.send({ hello: 'world' });
```

Child

```
process.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Message from parent:', msg);
});

try {
  let counter = 0;

  seTimeout(() => {
    process.send({ counter: counter++ });
  }, 1000);
} catch (err) {
  process.send({error: err.message});
}
```

Comment: @marekful, it is intentional, to throw an error

Comment: That's how child processes work. If you want a genuine process, you get to listen to process output and that's all you get. You'll have to design your parent so that it can examine the text on error, and do "something".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans do you mean the only option I have is to do something like in the "Update 2" example above?

Comment: Correct. `fork` is identical to `spawn` except that it's specifcally for spawning a new node process, so all you get to work with is the standard i/o interface.

Answer (score -2):

Why not to use the array of the [`option.stdio`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio)? This array has three elements `[subprocess.stdin, subprocess.stdout, subprocess.stderr]`, thus you just want to console the errors and not anything else.

Therefore you'd use `stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'inherit']`

## Parent

```js
const { execSync } = require('child_process')

try {
  execSync('node myNodeChildScript.js', { stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'inherit'] })
} catch (err) {
  console.error(Error(err))
  process.exit(1)
}
```

## Child

```js
console.log('Some log') // this will not be output to parent
if (someError()) {
  console.error('There was an error') // this will be output to parent console
  process.exit(1) // exit with error
}
```